# WPF TraceLevel problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm applying TraceLevel to a DataGrid like this

```
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,12,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Vals, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

but it doesn't produce any trace output. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings -> Data Binding

Set to warning or whatnot, think the default is off